# Falha ao carregar o helper "Unable to load the requested file: helpers/login_helper.php"

Tags: php, codeigniter

Bom dia pessoal, não consigo carregar meu helper com CodeIgniter, não faço ideia o que acontece:

meu autoload.php está assim:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'login');
```

e meu helper está assim:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by Andre Tohouca Lacomski on 02/04/2019
*/
if ( !defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
function is_logged_in() {
$CI =& get_instance();
$status = $CI->session->userdata('logged_in');
if (!isset($status)) {
    return false;
}else {
    return true;
}
}
?>
```

E aparece esse erro:

An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: helpers/login_helper.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheque as seguintes possibilidades que geram erro:

1. Seu arquivo helper está mesmo no diretório `../application/helpers`?
2. Seu arquivo se chamada mesmo `login_helper.php`?
3. Você programou em Windows depois fez deploy em Linux ou vice-versa? Nomes de arquivo com maiúsculas ou minúsculas diferentes passam a ser considerados arquivos diferentes também.

Comment: Acabei de achar o erro.... Escrevi login_heaper.php, agora deu certo